# LightBox with countdown close

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

My problem is that the first time I see the timer going down, but after that it goes strange and finally the browser crashes.

I'm putting here the code that gives me the error, it's a giant thing so I can not put it all here.

JavaScript:

```
// display the lightbox
function lightbox(insertContent) {

    // jQuery wrapper (optional, for compatibility only)
    (function($) {
        // add lightbox/shadow <div/>'s if not previously added
        if ($('#lightbox').size() === 0) {
            var theLightbox = $('<div id="lightbox"/>');
            var theShadow = $('<div id="lightbox-shadow"/>');
            var countDown = $('<div class="countDown"/>');
            $(theShadow).click(function(e) {
                closeLightbox();
            });
            $('body').append(theShadow);
            $('body').append(theLightbox);
            $('body').append(countDown);
        }

        // insert HTML content
        if (insertContent !== null) {
            $('#lightbox').html(insertContent);
            $('#lightbox').corner("15px");

            // ALWAYS LAST
            //$('#lightbox').append(countDown);
            CountDown(5);
        }

        // move the lightbox to the current window top + 100px
        $('#lightbox').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 100 + 'px');
        $('#lightbox-shadow').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
        $('.countDown').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 150 + "px");

        // display the lightbox
        $('#lightbox').show();
        $('#lightbox-shadow').show();
        $('.countDown').show();

    })(jQuery); // end jQuery wrapper
}

function CountDown(tiempo) {
    if (tiempo <= 0) {
        clearInterval(IntervalID);
        closeLightbox();
    } else {
        $(".countDown").html("Esta ventana se cerrará en " + tiempo + " segundos");
        tiempo--;
    }
    var IntervalID = setInterval("CountDown(" + tiempo + ")", 1000);
}

// close the lightbox


function closeLightbox() {

    // jQuery wrapper (optional, for compatibility only)
    (function($) {

        // hide lightbox/shadow <div/>'s
        $('#lightbox').hide();
        $('#lightbox-shadow').hide();
        $('.countDown').hide();

        // remove contents of lightbox in case a video or other content is actively playing
        $('#lightbox').empty();

    })(jQuery); // end jQuery wrapper
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Login").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        lightbox("Username Not Available");
        $("#lightbox").css("color", "#FF0000");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="Login" value="Hello">
```

CSS:

```
#lightbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: none;

    color: #069;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
}
#lightbox-shadow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    -moz-opacity: 0.90;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.90;
    opacity: 0.90;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}

.countDown {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1002;
    display: none;

    color: #069;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: none;
}
```

JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/c2gx9/6/

Don't know why it doesn't work on jsfiddle; it works well on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion, try using jsbin instead of jsfiddle. Your fiddle works better on jsbin than on jsfiddle.

Anyway, in `closeLightbox` you are executing `$('#lightbox').empty();` which will remove all children, but let the parent remain. Meaning after clearing the lightbox, there still is a div with the id lightbox.

The second time your `lightbox` is called, the condition `$('#lightbox').size() === 0` evaluates to false, as the element already exists.

To fix this, replace the line `$('#lightbox').empty();` with `$('#lightbox').remove();`

The second issue with the code is the way, you are calling `setInterval`.

```
function CountDown(tiempo) {
    if (tiempo <= 0) {
        clearInterval(IntervalID);
        closeLightbox();
    } else {
        $(".countDown").html("Esta ventana se cerrará en " + tiempo + " segundos");
        tiempo--;
    }

    var IntervalID = setInterval("CountDown(" + tiempo + ")", 1000);
}
```

The js engine translates the code to something like this

```
function CountDown(tiempo) {
    var IntervalID;

    if (tiempo <= 0) {
        clearInterval(IntervalID);
        closeLightbox();
    } else {
        $(".countDown").html("Esta ventana se cerrará en " + tiempo + " segundos");
        tiempo--;
    }

    IntervalID = setInterval("CountDown(" + tiempo + ")", 1000);
}
```

`IntervalID` is a variable local to the function. Each time the function is called, the variable is created from scratch. So in effect, you are never clearing the interval. You are only decrementing the `tiempo` variable.

A probable reason why the "browser goes mad" is that executing `setInterval` just once will repeatedly call the specified function till explicitly stopped. In your count down, over 5 iterations, you are calling `setInterval` 5 times. You can imagine that after a few tries, the browser is getting overloaded with all these simultaneously running instances of `CountDown`.

In future if you wish to use `setInterval`, you may want to [read the documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval). The site is a very good resource for HTML, JS & CSS.

Finally, you are passing the function name as a string argument to `setInterval`. It's kinda frowned upon for a variety of reasons. The reason I choose not to do so, is that the code will work only if the function is globally accessible. For the sake of encapsulation and not polluting the global namespace, people recommend other approaches.

Coming back to how to fix this, I should have noticed the `setInterval` bug the first time round. I didn't and that's my bad. You have found a solution that works for you. For completeness sake, I will include how I would have asked you to fix it.

```
function CountDown(tiempo) {
    if (tiempo <= 0) {
        closeLightbox();

    } else {
        $(".countDown").html("Esta ventana se cerrará en " + tiempo + " segundos");
        tiempo--;

        setTimeout(function () { 
            CountDown(tiempo);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Amith, thank you for your answer, i changed that but still doesn't work as espected. It runs ok the first time but after that goes mad, I changed setInterval with setTimeout now the browser doesn't stuck. I think I have an error at the CountDown function.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I should have noticed the bug in `CountDown` in the first attempt itself. Anyway, I have updated my answer with an explanation of what was wrong with your earlier code and one possible solution to fix it. Let me know if that fixes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Found some code on the net and it finally works, the code I am useing now is:

JS:

```
// display the lightbox
function lightbox(insertContent){

    // jQuery wrapper (optional, for compatibility only)
    (function($) {
        // add lightbox/shadow <div/>'s if not previously added
        if($('#lightbox').size() === 0){
            var theLightbox = $('<div id="lightbox"/>');
            var theShadow = $('<div id="lightbox-shadow"/>');
            var countDown = $('<div id="countDown"/>');
            $(theShadow).click(function(e){
                closeLightbox();
            });
            $('body').append(theShadow);
            $('body').append(theLightbox);
            $('body').append(countDown);
        }

        // insert HTML content
        if(insertContent !== null){
            $('#lightbox').html(insertContent);
            $('#lightbox').corner("15px");

            // ALWAYS LAST
            $('#lightbox').append(countDown);
            CreateTimer(3);
        }

        // move the lightbox to the current window top + 100px
        $('#lightbox').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 100 + 'px');
        $('#lightbox-shadow').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
        //$('#countDown').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 150 + "px");

        // display the lightbox
        $('#lightbox').show();
        $('#lightbox-shadow').show();
        $('#countDown').show();

    })(jQuery); // end jQuery wrapper

}

function CreateTimer(Tiempo) {
    TotalSeconds = Tiempo;

    UpdateTimer();
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}

function Tick() {
    if (TotalSeconds <= 1) {
        closeLightbox();
        return;
    }

    TotalSeconds -= 1;
    UpdateTimer();
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}

function UpdateTimer() {
    $('#countDown').html("Esta ventana se cerrará en " + TotalSeconds + " segundos");
}

// close the lightbox
function closeLightbox(){

    // jQuery wrapper (optional, for compatibility only)
    (function($) {

        // hide lightbox/shadow <div/>'s
        $('#lightbox').remove();
        $('#lightbox-shadow').remove();
        $('#countDown').remove();

        // remove contents of lightbox in case a video or other content is actively playing


    })(jQuery); // end jQuery wrapper

}
```